# Terminology: looking for a word to describe dynamic CMS inclusions

Tags: xml, tags, content-management-system

In most content management systems there is a feature which lets a developer insert a value into the HTML code of a page style or template, which will reproduce a specific value at publish-time. Examples:

```
<title>Welcome to the &dept; Department</title>
<h1>Tasks for <?cms #insert date()?></h1>
<p>For details, please email <foo type="123" renderas="link"/></p>
<li>
  <?php call to insert list items here?>
</li>
```

I'm looking for a suitable generic term to describe these, for use in documentation. They insert fragments, which could be anything from a single word (like &dept; could be in XML), right up to whole slabs of HTML, as in the PHP "example". The thing they all have in common is that they get parsed away at publish time and dereferenced, so that the page acquires the value in their place.

Some, like General Entities or Processing Instructions have XML-specific names, but others are just markup-like objects.

Insertions? Private Tags? Template Replacements? What do the various CMS systems call them?

P

Answer (score 1):

[ECMA-376 (Office Open XML)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-376,%20Fourth%20Edition,%20Part%201%20-%20Fundamentals%20And%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.zip) and [Microsoft Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-in-Word-b0536e6f-5a23-4408-b90f-e7fc24c75416), use the term, ***field***, to describe the feature that allows content to be dynamically determined and inserted into a document.

Here are the categories of fields listed in section 17.16.5 Field definitions of *ECMA-376 Office Open XML Part 1 - Fundamentals and Markup Language Reference*, 4th edition:

- Category
- Date and Time
- Document Automation
- Document Information
- Equations and Formulas
- Form Fields
- Index and Tables
- Links and References
- Mail Merge
- Numbering
- User Information

Comment: Thank you — I should have known that and thought to look. That seems to cover the equivalents of insertion of short values (names, dates, labels, etc). But it unfortunately doesn't cover the insertion of arbitrarily large chunks of text from elsewhere at the paragraph level, AFAICS (unless that's under 'Document Automation').

Comment: You're welcome.  There are over 70 fields among those categories that do everything but serve tea.  Arbitrarily large chunks of text could be inserted in several different ways: In *Links and References* there's `INCLUDEDTEXT` or `AUTOTEXT`; in *Mail Merge*, there's `DATABASE`; etc.

Comment: Thanks. Look like "field" is the term (a pity IMHO, since it already carries a heavy semantic load, and may not actually be instantiated as a field at all in a CMS — ah well…)